# GM_setValue working alternative

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

Until today GM_setValue was working perfect. I have actual version of GreaseMonkey and FF. And today it stopped working. In current version and latest version i have "GM_setValue is undefined". Also GM_setValue stopped working. I didn't change anything in script, nor in browser (maybe it updated in background?) How to fix it?

Comment: Which version of Firefox & GM? I have FF 29.01, GM 1.15 and `GM_setValue` works fine. Have you added it to `// @grant         GM_setValue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the `@grant` option in the header to allow GM methods?